# KDE5 : a mix of UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1

Tags: arch-linux, kde, unicode

Since (I think) I upgraded Plasma to version 5, KDE applications seem to open my files (encoded in UTF-8) as in ISO-8859-1.
I am not very familiar with locales problems... I am french, so a lot of files, filenames, and messages from console need to have accents (éàêù etc.)
Here are results of some commands in konsole :

```
> felandral@ultralinux /home/fel % locale -a
C
en_US.utf8
french
fr_FR
fr_FR@euro
fr_FR.iso88591
fr_FR.iso885915@euro
fr_FR.utf8
POSIX
> felandral@ultralinux /home/fel % locale
LANG=fr_FR.ISO-8859-1
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.ISO-8859-1"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.ISO-8859-1"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.ISO-8859-1"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.ISO-8859-1"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.ISO-8859-1"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.ISO-8859-1"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.ISO-8859-1"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.ISO-8859-1"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.ISO-8859-1"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.ISO-8859-1"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.ISO-8859-1"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.ISO-8859-1"
LC_ALL=
> felandral@ultralinux /home/fel % sudo localectl
Mot de passe [sudo] de felandral�:
   System Locale: LANG=fr_FR.utf8
       VC Keymap: fr-pc
      X11 Layout: fr
       X11 Model: pc105
     X11 Options: terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

Note that in tty, there is no problems. But with Kate, digikam, konsole, dolphin, etc. I can't manipulate my files or files from other systems, due to this problem.